# How can I figure out which hash function was used?

Tags: hash

I'm developing a network API to interact with a legacy server, and I need a little help figuring out which hashing function they're using.  The original developers are not particularly responsive to my queries, so I thought that SO might help me out.

This is a low-security, internal corporate network, so the hash isn't complicated.  So far, I have determined that plaintext "ashafer" is hashed into 0xfd1873ca

So, I'm trying to identify a simple hash function that turns strings into 32-bit hex numbers.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I put "ashafer" into http://boldizsar.palotas.eu/crypto.php , it returns 4246238154 for the crc-32, which is 0xfd1873ca in hex, so they're using plain old crc-32.

Answer (score 1):

Crc32 do it.
Obviously it is not md5 or shaX (all of them are 128)

Oops, just checked.. crc32 "ashafer"=0x6074acb4

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what language the legacy server was written in? For example, it could be "the default .NET hash code implementation" (or ditto for Java). Let's hope not, as you're *really* not meant to use them like that, but it's a possibility...